# Why are some tags changed automatically?

Tags: discussion, editing, tags

Sometimes when I edit a question, I choose a tag but it doesn't taken into account. Is someone can tell me why some tags are changed automatically?

For example, I have edited a question by addind the *url-format* tag but it's changed to *url* tag.

Comment: Can you give an example? My guess is that the tag is a synonym of the one that replaced it.

Comment: Thanks John, that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some tags are "synonyms" of other tags.  If you use one of those tags, they will be automatically changed to their synonym.  For example [stats](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stats) becomes [statistics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics). You can see the list here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: Thanks Stephen, you're right.